# NullPointerException when moving Path in touch event handler

Tags: android, button, undo

I am trying to implement undo in my drawing app but i have seen a problem in my onTouch Event method. the all undo methods are described in below code.

**onTouchEvent**

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

  switch (ev.getAction()) {

   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    {
     touchStarted(x, y);
     x = (int) ev.getX();
     y = (int) ev.getY();
     r = MainActivity.mSeekBar.getProgress();
     TOUCH_TOLERANCE = MainActivity.mbutton.getProgress();
     invalidate();

     break;
    }

   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    {
     touchMoved(x, y);
     x = (int) ev.getX();
     y = (int) ev.getY();
     r = MainActivity.mSeekBar.getProgress();

     invalidate();
     break;

    }

   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    touchEnded();
    break;

  }
  return true;
 } * * strong text * *
```

**onTouchStarted**

```
private void touchStarted(float x, float y) {

 mPath.reset();
 mPath = new Path();
 paths.add(mPath);
 mPath.moveTo(x, y);

 mX = x;
 mY = y;
}
```

**onTouchMoved**

```
private void touchMoved(float x, float y) {
 float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
 float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
 if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
  mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
  mX = x;
  mY = y;
 }
}
```

**TouchEnded**

```
private void touchEnded() {
 mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
 pcanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

 Toast.makeText(getContext(), "touchEnded" + paths.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onClickUndo() {
 Toast.makeText(getContext(), "before undo button pressed " + paths.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 if (paths.size() > 0) {
  undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "after undo button pressed " + paths.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  Log.i("UNDOING", "PREPARE INVALIDATE");
  invalidate();
  Log.i("UNDOING", "FINISH INVALIDATE");
 } else Toast.makeText(getContext(), "nothing to undo" + paths.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**LogCat**

```
com.example.laptop.rugh E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.laptop.rugh, PID: 2253
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.laptop.rugh.CustomView.touchStarted(CustomView.java:189)
        at com.example.laptop.rugh.CustomView.onTouchEvent(CustomView.java:159)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8070)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2434)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2123)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2434)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2123)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2434)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2123)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2434)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2123)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2434)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2123)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2434)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2123)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2311)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1606)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2617)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2259)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8265)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4693)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4554)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4112)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4135)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4246)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4143)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4303)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4112)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4135)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4143)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4112)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6489)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6406)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6377)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6342)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6569)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: i want to do the undo method work through the button but how to pass button reference in onTouchEvent method

Comment: this is my first question plz dont close

Comment: no worries, retracted the close vote. Please elaborate the question with details of what you tried and what issues you are facing.

Comment: i am trying to work the undo method through button . i have button in my main Activity. how i pass the button in these methods.@AndroidMechanic

Comment: Please state the exception or the error or the functionality you want to achieve.

Comment: Check out my logcat@zek54

Comment: You should change the question's title to elaborate what the problem is.

Comment: @hushan please take what is the line on CustomView.java:159 and CustomView.java:189

Comment: Line 159 is touchStarted(x,y) and 189 is touchMoved(x,y) in onTouchEvent Method@YuriyKolbasinskiy

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code, I'm guessing `mPath` is null.

Comment: _"and 189 is touchMoved(x,y) in onTouchEvent Method"_ That doesn't seem likely. According to the stacktrace line 189 is in `touchStarted` In any case, you need to fix whatever you're doing on that line that tries to dereference a null object reference.

Comment: my onClickUndo method is not working@Michael